# How do I write Perl object with plugins?

Tags: perl

How do I write Perl objects with extensible code?  Im thinking drivers, or some configuation, where the user can pass in a string "Classname::Class" or something.  Thanks.

For example, for a graph class:

```
my $spg = Graph::ShortestPathGraph->new;
$spg->Algorithm( "Graph::DFS" );
$spg->solve;

$spg->Algorithm( "Graph::BFS" );
$spg->solve;
```

Comment: Please provide a more detailed example of what you are trying to solve.  Some pseudo code would be good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do I write extensible code?

With planning.  Let's say you are writing an algorithm for plotting a
set of points.  You need a source of those points, a place to plot
them, and an algorithm for interpolating points that aren't in the
set.

(And just a note, assume that "graph" means "chart" here, rather than
a graph in the discrete math sense.)

Let's define roles that represent those operations.  A source of
points must be able to provide us with the points:

```
 package Graphomatic::PointSource;
 use Moose::Role;

 requires 'get_points'; # return a list of points

 1;
```

A plotter must allow us to plot a point:

```
 package Graphomatic::Plot;
 use Moose::Role;

 requires 'plot_point'; # plot a point
 requires 'show_graph'; # show the final graph

 1;
```

And an interpolater must give us a point when given two nearby points:

```
 package Graphomatic::Interpolate;
 use Moose::Role;

 requires 'interpolate_point';

 1;
```

Now, we just need to write our main application in terms of these
roles:

```
 package Graphomatic;
 use Moose;

 use Graphomatic::PointSource;
 use Graphomatic::Plot;
 use Graphomatic::Interpolate;

 has 'source' => (
     is       => 'ro',
     does     => 'Graphomatic::PointSource',
     handles  => 'Graphomatic::PointSource',
     required => 1,
 );

 has 'plot' => (
     is       => 'ro',
     does     => 'Graphomatic::Plot',
     handles  => 'Graphomatic::Plot',
     required => 1,
 );

 has 'interpolate' => (
     is       => 'ro',
     does     => 'Graphomatic::Interpolate',
     handles  => 'Graphomatic::Interpolate',
     required => 1,
 );

 sub run { # actually render and display the graph
     my $self = shift;

     my @points = $self->get_points; # delegated from the PointSource
     for my $x (some minimum .. some maximum) {
         my ($a, $b) = nearest_points( $x, @points );
         $self->plot_point( $self->interpolate_point($a, $b, $x) );
     }

     $self->show_graph;
 }

 1;
```

Now it's a simple matter of defining some source implementations.
Let's read points from a file:

```
package Graphomatic::PointSource::File;

use Moose;
use MooseX::FileAttribute;

# ensure, at compile-time, that this class is a valid point
# source
with 'Graphomatic::PointSource';

has_file 'dataset' => ( must_exist => 1, required => 1 );

sub get_points {
    my $self = shift;

    return parse $self->dataset->slurp;
}

1;
```

And plot to the Z window system:

```
package Graphomatic::Plot::Z;
use Moose;
use Z;

with 'Graphomatic::Plot';

has 'window' => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Z::Window', lazy_build => 1);

sub _build_window { return Z->new_window }

sub plot_point {
    my ($self, $point) = @_;

    $self->window->plot_me_a_point_kthx($point->x, $point->y);
}

sub show_plot {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->window->show;
}

1;
```

And interpolate with a random number generator (hey, I'm lazy, and I'm
not going to look up bicubic interpolation :P):

```
package Graphomatic::Interpolate::Random;
use Moose;

with 'Graphomatic::Interpolate';

sub interpolate_point {
    my ($self, $a, $b, $x) = @_;
    return 4; # chosen by fair dice roll.
              # guaranteed to be random.
}

1;
```

Now we can assemble all the pieces into a working program:

```
use Graphomatic::PointSource::File;
use Graphomatic::Plot::Z;
use Graphomatic::Interpolate::Random;

my $graphomatic = Graphomatic->new(
   source => Graphomatic::PointSource::File->new(
       file => 'data.dat',
   ),
   plot        => Graphomatic::Plot::Z->new,
   interpolate => Graphomatic::Interpolate::Random->new,
);

$graphomatic->run;
```

Now you can cleanly customize any of the parts without affecting the
other parts, simply by implementing new classes that "do" the required
roles.  (If they say 'with ...' and they don't meet the requirements,
you will get an error as soon as you load the class.  If you try to
use an instance as a parameter that doesn't "do" the right role, the
constructor will die.

Type safety, it's a wonderful thing.)

As for handling config files, just read names and parameters somehow,
and then:

```
my $interpolate_class = get_config('interpolate_class');
Class::MOP::load_class($interpolate_class);
my $interpolate = $interpolate_class->new( %interpolate_class_args );

my $graphomatic = Graphomatic->new( interpolate => $interpolate, ... );
```

[MooseX::YAML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX::YAML) is a nice way of automating this.

Answer (score 3):

[Module::Pluggable](http://search.cpan.org/~simonw/Module-Pluggable-3.9/lib/Module/Pluggable.pm) might help you to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/Moose-0.99/lib/Moose.pm), and [MooseX::Types::LoadableClass](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/MooseX-Types-LoadableClass-0.001/lib/MooseX/Types/LoadableClass.pm)

```
package MyClass;
use Moose;
use MooseX::Types::LoadableClass qw/ClassName/;

has 'algo' => (
    is => 'ro'
    , isa => ClassName
    , coerce => 1
);

sub solve {
    my $self = shift;
    my $algo = $self->algo->new;
    # stuff using algo
}


## These work:
Graph::ShortestPathGraph->new({ algo => 'Graph::DFS' })->solve;
Graph::ShortestPathGraph->new({ algo => 'Graph::BFS' })->solve;

## As does this:
my $gspg = Graph::ShortestPathGraph->new;
$gspg->algo('Graph::BFS');
$gspg->solve;
```

If the class does not exist, an error is thrown. If, however, you want to create the Algo classes yourself, you're probably much better off making them [Traits](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/MooseX-Traits-0.08/lib/MooseX/Traits.pm).

There are a ton of pre-made solutions using Moose to solve this problem, look around on CPAN.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple home made example. Once you understand it, you can move on to modules that are intended to take the tedium out of this sort of thing:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Me::Mine;

use base 'Class::Accessor';

__PACKAGE__->mk_accessors( qw( dumper ) );

sub dump {
    my $self = shift;
    my $dumper = $self->dumper;
    eval "require $dumper";
    print "Dumping using $dumper\n", $dumper->Dump([ $self ]);
    return;
}

package main;

use strict; use warnings;

my $me = Me::Mine->new;
my $you = Me::Mine->new;

$me->dumper('Data::Dumper');
$you->dumper('YAML');

$_->dump for $me, $you;
```

Output:

```
Dumping using Data::Dumper
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'dumper' => 'Data::Dumper'
               }, 'Me::Mine' );
Dumping using YAML
--- YAML
---
- !!perl/hash:Me::Mine
  dumper: YAML
```

Comment: Don't do `eval "require $dumper"`. That makes me a sad friedo. It's not so hard to convert the module name to its filename. There's even a handy CPAN item for it: http://search.cpan.org/~mattlaw/Module-Util/lib/Module/Util.pm#module_path

Comment: @friedo Can you expand on that? I mean, this is throwaway code just to illustrate a technique so there is no error/parameter checking, but what specifically is so wrong with `eval "require $dumper"` (as recommended by http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html ?

Comment: I have a (perhaps irrational) aversion to string `eval` in all its forms, unless it's absolutely necessary for something. In this case, it's not necessary, because it's easy to get the module filename, so you can use `my $mod_file = module_path $dumper; require $mod_file;`.