# How to dynamic load plugin files in perl?

Tags: perl

My project struct:

```
Test.pm
Plugins/Plugin1.pm
Plugins/Plugin2.pm
```

test.pm looks like:

```
sub new{
#how to dynamic load plugins?
```

plugin1,plugs2 provide same api, say, `sub run {#...}`

perl script looks like:

```
my $test=Test->new("Plugin1");
$test->run ;#should call Plugin1->run
```

So how to dynamic load plugins in test.pm?

Is there any good framework to help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025261/how-can-i-find-all-the-packages-that-inherit-from-a-package-in-perl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478009/how-do-i-write-perl-object-with-plugins http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815432/what-is-the-best-option-for-building-a-plugin-system-for-a-moose-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301959/dynamically-loading-perl-modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a more complete answer:

First, take a look at:

1. [How can I conditionally import a package in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957498/how-can-i-conditionally-import-a-package-in-perl)
2. [In Perl, is it better to use a module than to require a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180554/in-perl-is-it-better-to-use-a-module-than-to-require-a-file)

The answer to the question in the first link is what you want:

```
eval {
    require Plugin1;
    Plugin1->import();
};  
if ($@) {
    warn "Error including Foobar: $@";
}
```

But for your case, since your module name could be a string you need to:

```
eval {
    my $module_name = 'Plugin1.pm';
    require $module_name;
    $module_name =~ s/\.pm//;
    $module_name->import();
};
if ($@) {
    # handle error here
}
```

`import` will allow you to use the already exported subroutines from `Plugin1`. e.g. If `func()` is exported in `Plugin1`, you can call it with `func()` and not `Plugin1::func()`

Also this whole thing is better put in `BEGIN {};` in your `Test.pm` module. Otherwise `import()` may not take effect.

Comment: Also, have a look at `Module::Load`. It will save you and possibly others time and energy.

Comment: This will fail when `Path/Plugin1.pm`

Answer (score 4):

```
eval {
    require $plugin;
}
if($@) # try another one or report error or whatever ...
```

That's basically all you need; not complicated enough to need a module. You can wrap it in a `BEGIN {}` block if you need to do it early during compilation of the module.

Comment: this is not right thing to do. This will fail if `$plugin` not file name. Here is better approach: `eval "require $plugin; 1"`

Answer (score 2):

[`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) loads a module:

```
require "Plugins/Plugin1.pm";
```

This can fail, so you need to handle errors.

`use` is for compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

[Module::PluginFinder](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::PluginFinder)

```
use Module::PluginFinder qw( );

my $finder = Module::PluginFinder->new(
   search_path => 'Plugins',
);

my $test = $finder->construct("Plugin1");
$test->run();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something special on errors:

```
sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  ...;
  for my $plugin (@_){
    if( eval "require $plugin" ){
      # successful
      ...;
    }else{
      # unsuccessful
      die $@;
    }
  }
  ...;
}
```

Otherwise just use:

```
sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  ...;
  for my $plugin (@_){
    eval "require $plugin" or die $@;
    # successful
    ...;
  }
  ...;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sufficient approach is:

```
eval "require $plugin_class; 1"   or die "Error";
```

You can look into modern framework [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/) [`Mojo::Loader`](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-7.60/lib/Mojo/Loader.pm#L37) to see how that done.